# Couldn't install npm packages - bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, lerna

I'm trying to npm install (note: via lerna bootstrap) a project in Ubuntu 18.04. I face an error (npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
) and could not move forward.

I've tried installing node-gyp, node-pre-gyp and apt-get build-essentials as well, believing it could be because of C++ compilation issue, but no luck.

Versions:
Node: v10.16.0
NPM: 6.9.0

```
ren@renish:~/Src/company$ sudo npm run bootstrap
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /bin/node but npm is using /snap/node/2485/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> company@ bootstrap /home/ren/Src/company
> npm install && npx lerna bootstrap

npm WARN company@ No repository field.
npm WARN company@ No license field.

audited 43804 packages in 3.726s
found 41 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
lerna notice cli v3.15.0
lerna info Bootstrapping 7 packages
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in 'company_api'
lerna ERR! npm install stdout:

> bcrypt@3.0.6 install /home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

Failed to execute '/snap/node/2485/bin/node /snap/node/2485/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)

lerna ERR! npm install stderr:
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.6 and node@10.16.1 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib' 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-25-generic
gyp ERR! command "/snap/node/2485/bin/node" "/snap/node/2485/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/snap/node/2485/bin/node /snap/node/2485/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-25-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/snap/node/2485/bin/node" "/home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/ren/Src/company/packages/api/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ren/.npm/_logs/2019-08-16T13_52_33_286Z-debug.log

lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in 'company_api'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 1 child process to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! company@ bootstrap: `npm install && npx lerna bootstrap`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the company@ bootstrap script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ren/.npm/_logs/2019-08-16T13_52_33_951Z-debug.log
```

Could someone throw some light on this?

Comment: Looks like you've got a simple file permission problem. That's what the EACCESS error is telling you.

Comment: It is not file permission issue(I give sudo chmod 777 -R node_modules/ and also use sudo on command). May be it is node version problem. Please check with version 8.11  and yarn and let me know problem persists

Comment: Yes @Ashok it doesn't seem to be a permission issue. I tried the same, no luck. The same code works well in a different system (ubuntu & mac) with same node & npm version.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is a version AND a access problem is pretty clear in the error message. changing the permission is one step but it looks like you need to update your:

node

`gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok`

and also your system linux version for some reason :
`gyp ERR! System Linux 5.0.0-25-generic`

Comment: to what version of node and npm we should take it to. Can you please explain it.